# Convert List[Any] to List[Int]

Tags: scala

How can I convert

```
List(1, 2, "3")
```

to

```
List(1, 2, 3)
```

since `List(1, 2, "3")` is of type `List[Any]` and I can't use `.toInt` on `Any`.

Comment: How did you end up with a list like that in the first place? You should just convert all the strings into ints before you put them in the list.

Comment: The code is bypassing the type system.I.e., errors that the compiler could detect at compile time, will occur at runtime.

Comment: It's actually nasty homework :-)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That should be sufficient solution:

```
l.map(_.toString.toInt)
```

Comment: or with a single `map` call `l.map(_.toString().toInt)`

Comment: what if i have nulls in the list. How should i handle it?

Comment: You should not have nulls in scala... You have `Option` for that. So your list type signature should be `List[Option[Any]]` then you should be able to `collect` values: `List(None, Some(1), Some("2")).collect{case Some(a) => a.toString.toInt}`. Nevertheless you can  `List(null, 1, "2").map(Option(_))` and then collect (or just use `if a != null` guard in `case` statement, but that is very not "scala-ish").

Answer (score 2):

Starting `Scala 2.13` and the introduction of [`String#toIntOption`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/StringOps.html#toIntOption:Option[Int]), we can make [@liosedhel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22442553/9297144) a bit safer if needs be:

```
// val l: List[Any] = List(1, 2, "3")
l.flatMap(_.toString.toIntOption)
// List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```